# How to use a 'list' variable within this task

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and am currently working to put together a playbook to deploy some Palo Alto configuration using the following modules:

https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/ansible-pan

I have been at this thing for a week now trying to work it out and I can't quite figure out why this 'list' isn't working.  In summary, this code connects to the firewall, creates a new address object and if a 'service' variable exists that says http or https then it will add this object to an existing firewall address group.

The problem is with the addition to the firewall group. The task that accomplishes this seems to overwrite the existing objects within the group instead of appending to it.

To try and combat this I have a task that 'finds' the existing objects (results are within a dictionary which I then  to a list variable.  This variable + the new server variable are then used in the 'static_value' job to update the address group.  This doesn't seem to work and looks like it is exceeding a character limit as if it is one string.

I have also attempted to re-add the existing objects on their own and this also fails with the following:

```
"msg": "Failed apply:  DevUKST-Web-Servers -> static '['UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01', 'UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01']' is not a valid reference\n DevUKST-Web-Servers -> static is invalid"
}
```

The one time I can get it to work in a way is when using a 'with_items' loop in the 'Add EFW objects to address group if 80/443' task to populate the static_values.  It loops through the 'result' from the find objects task and adds the new address object 'efwone' on the end.  The issue with this is that it overwrites with each result each time it loops.

This is the playbook I am running

```
---

 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: false

   roles:
    - role: PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "username"
      prompt: "Enter Username"
    - name: "password"
      prompt: "Enter Password"

  vars:
     cli:
         ip_address: x.x.x.x
         username: "{{ username }}"
         password: "{{ password }}"
         port: 443  

     objects: []
     efwone: "{{ hostname }}-NAT-EFW-01"

  tasks: 
    - name: include variables (free-form)
      tags: [dev, prod]
      include_vars: vars.yml   
      no_log: 'false'

 # Configure Address Objects

    - name: Create object "NAT-EFW-01"
      tags: [dev, prod]
      panos_address_object:
         provider: "{{ cli }}"
         name: "{{ hostname }}-NAT-EFW-01"
         value: "{{ efw01_serviceip }}"
         description: "{{ service_name }} - Public LB Backend pool IP"
         commit: false

    - name: Create object "Server Object"
      tags: [dev, prod]
      panos_address_object:
          provider: "{{ cli }}"
          name: "{{ hostname }}"
          value: "{{ serverip }}"
          description: "{{ service_name }} - {{ service_type }}"
          commit: false

 # Find existing objects in webserver address group

    - name: Find objects in address group
      tags: dev
      when: service == "http" or service == "https"
      panos_object_facts:
       provider: "{{ cli }}"
       name: "{{ dgshort }}-Web-Servers"
       object_type: "address-group"
      register: output

    - name: Display Output
      tags: [dev, prod]
      debug: msg="{{ output.results.static_value }}"

    - name: Display efwone
      tags: [dev, prod]
      debug: var=efwone


    - name: Populate list with address objects
      tags: [dev, prod]
      set_fact: 
         objects: "{{ output.results.static_value + [ efwone ] }}"

    - name: Display new object list
      tags: [dev, prod]
      debug: var=objects

# Add EFW objects to address group if 80/443

    - name: Update Web-Servers group dev
      tags: dev
      when: service == "http" or service == "https"
      panos_address_group:
       provider: "{{ cli }}"
       name: "{{ dgshort }}-Web-Servers"
       static_value: [ "{{ objects }}" ]
       commit: false
```

```
Module:

#  Copyright 2018 Palo Alto Networks, Inc
#
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#  limitations under the License.

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
__metaclass__ = type

ANSIBLE_METADATA = {'metadata_version': '1.1',
                    'status': ['preview'],
                    'supported_by': 'community'}

DOCUMENTATION = '''
---
module: panos_address_group
short_description: Create address group objects on PAN-OS devices.
description:
    - Create address group objects on PAN-OS devices.
author:
    - Michael Richardson (@mrichardson03)
    - Garfield Lee Freeman (@shinmog)
version_added: "2.8"
requirements:
    - pan-python can be obtained from PyPI U(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pan-python)
    - pandevice can be obtained from PyPI U(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandevice)
notes:
    - Panorama is supported.
    - Check mode is supported.
extends_documentation_fragment:
    - panos.transitional_provider
    - panos.vsys
    - panos.device_group
    - panos.state
options:
    name:
        description:
            - Name of address group to create.
        required: true
    static_value:
        description:
            - List of address objects to be included in the group.
        type: list
    dynamic_value:
        description:
            - Registered IP tags for a dynamic address group.
        type: string
    description:
        description:
            - Descriptive name for this address group.
    tag:
        description:
            - List of tags to add to this address group.
        type: list
    commit:
        description:
            - Commit changes after creating object.  If I(ip_address) is a Panorama device, and I(device_group) is
              also set, perform a commit to Panorama and a commit-all to the device group.
        default: true
        type: bool
'''

EXAMPLES = '''
- name: Create object group 'Prod'
  panos_address_group:
    provider: '{{ provider }}'
    name: 'Prod'
    static_value: ['Test-One', 'Test-Three']
    tag: ['Prod']
- name: Create object group 'SI'
  panos_address_group:
    provider: '{{ provider }}'
    name: 'SI'
    dynamic_value: "'SI_Instances'"
    tag: ['SI']
- name: Delete object group 'SI'
  panos_address_group:
    provider: '{{ provider }}'
    name: 'SI'
    state: 'absent'
'''

RETURN = '''
# Default return values
'''

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible.module_utils.network.panos.panos import get_connection


try:
    from pandevice.objects import AddressGroup
    from pandevice.errors import PanDeviceError
except ImportError:
    pass


def main():
    helper = get_connection(
        vsys=True,
        device_group=True,
        with_classic_provider_spec=True,
        with_state=True,
        required_one_of=[
            ['static_value', 'dynamic_value'],
        ],
        argument_spec=dict(
            name=dict(type='str', required=True),
            static_value=dict(type='list'),
            dynamic_value=dict(),
            description=dict(),
            tag=dict(type='list'),
            commit=dict(type='bool', default=True),
        ),
    )
    mutually_exclusive = [
        ['static_value', 'dynamic_value']
    ]

    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=helper.argument_spec,
        required_one_of=helper.required_one_of,
        mutually_exclusive=mutually_exclusive,
        supports_check_mode=True,
    )

    # Verify libs are present, get parent object.
    parent = helper.get_pandevice_parent(module)

    # Object params.
    spec = {
        'name': module.params['name'],
        'static_value': module.params['static_value'],
        'dynamic_value': module.params['dynamic_value'],
        'description': module.params['description'],
        'tag': module.params['tag'],
    }

    # Other info.
    commit = module.params['commit']

    # Retrieve current info.
    try:
        listing = AddressGroup.refreshall(parent, add=False)
    except PanDeviceError as e:
        module.fail_json(msg='Failed refresh: {0}'.format(e))

    # Build the object based on the user spec.
    obj = AddressGroup(**spec)
    parent.add(obj)

    # Apply the state.
    changed = helper.apply_state(obj, listing, module)

    # Commit.
    if commit and changed:
        helper.commit(module)

    # Done.
    module.exit_json(changed=changed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

These are the results

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null, 
            "device_group": "shared", 
            "ip_address": null, 
            "name": "DevUKST-Web-Servers", 
            "name_regex": null, 
            "object_type": "address-group", 
            "password": null, 
            "port": 443, 
            "provider": {
                "api_key": null, 
                "ip_address": "x.x.x.x", 
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                "port": 443, 
                "serial_number": null, 
                "username": "xxxx"
            }, 
            "username": "admin", 
            "vsys": "vsys1"
        }
    }, 
    "objects": [
        {
            "description": null, 
            "dynamic_value": null, 
            "name": "DevUKST-Web-Servers", 
            "static_value": [
                "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
                "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01"
            ], 
            "tag": null
        }
    ], 
    "results": {
        "description": null, 
        "dynamic_value": null, 
        "name": "DevUKST-Web-Servers", 
        "static_value": [
            "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
            "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01"
        ], 
        "tag": null
    }
}

TASK [Display Output] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/NETOPS/AZURE/PALO/deployserviceparams.yml:91
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
        "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01"
    ]
}

TASK [Display efwone] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/NETOPS/AZURE/PALO/deployserviceparams.yml:95
ok: [localhost] => {
    "efwone": "Test-NAT-EFW-01"
}

TASK [Populate list with address objects] **************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/NETOPS/AZURE/PALO/deployserviceparams.yml:100
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "objects": [
            "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
            "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01", 
            "Test-NAT-EFW-01"
        ]
    }, 
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Display new object list] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/NETOPS/AZURE/PALO/deployserviceparams.yml:105
ok: [localhost] => {
    "objects": [
        "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
        "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01", 
        "Test-NAT-EFW-01"
    ]
}

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null, 
            "commit": false, 
            "description": null, 
            "device_group": "shared", 
            "dynamic_value": null, 
            "ip_address": null, 
            "name": "DevUKST-Web-Servers", 
            "password": null, 
            "port": 443, 
            "provider": {
                "api_key": null, 
                "ip_address": "x.x.x.x", 
                "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
                "port": 443, 
                "serial_number": null, 
                "username": "xxxxx"
            }, 
            "state": "present", 
            "static_value": [
                [
                    "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
                    "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01", 
                    "Test-NAT-EFW-01"
                ]
            ], 
            "tag": null, 
            "username": "admin", 
            "vsys": "vsys1"
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Failed apply:  DevUKST-Web-Servers -> static Node can be at most 63 characters, but current length: 77 value: ['UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01', 'UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01', 'Test-NAT-EFW-01']...\n DevUKST-Web-Servers -> static is invalid"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer** This is a totally blind debugging as I can't reproduce anything from your original post. Always consider making [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if this is possible.

---

The [inline documentation of your module for the `static_value` parameter](https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/ansible-pan/blob/6da2d7b4b8d658f1503e9ff4bb137d1cee32b08a/library/panos_address_group.py#L51) clearly states it's waiting for a list of 'address objects':

```
static_value:
    description:
        - List of address objects to be included in the group.
    type: list
```

**Note**: I'm blindly assuming from the rest of your post that a string is a valid address object

In the output of your run, we can see that what you send is **not a list** of adress objects **but a list of lists** of address objects

```
    "static_value": [
                [
                    "UKST1MXWEB002D-NAT-EFW-01", 
                    "UKST1MXWEB003D-NAT-EFW-01", 
                    "Test-NAT-EFW-01"
                ]
            ]
```

The problematic line of your playbook that leads to this situation is in your last task:

```
static_value: [ "{{ objects }}" ]
```

Your last task should be (notice the gone brackets)

```
    - name: Update Web-Servers group dev
      tags: dev
      when: service == "http" or service == "https"
      panos_address_group:
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        name: "{{ dgshort }}-Web-Servers"
        static_value: "{{ objects }}"
        commit: false
```

Comment: I can't believe how simple that was!  Thank you very much.  I never even noticed that this was a list within a list, until you pointed it out.  Looking at the results now its actually quite obvious with the 2 sets of [].

Comment: If this fixes your problem, you should accept the answer to let others know there is a actual solution.